# Not well formatted -XML to Json Conversion

Tags: java, xml, json

```
<list>
<interfaceReachability  type="Critical" count="345" httpLink="searchLradIfAction_pageId?isAscending=true&operation=monitor&searchApByType=AllTypes&searchRadioTypeallRadios=true&searchApType=homePage&severity=1" />
<interfaceReachability  type="No Alarms" count="6216" httpLink="searchLradIfAction_pageId?isAscending=true&operation=monitor&searchApByType=AllTypes&searchRadioTypeallRadios=true&searchApType=homePage&severity=5" />
<interfaceReachability  type="Minor" count="145" httpLink="searchLradIfAction_pageId?isAscending=true&operation=monitor&searchApByType=AllTypes&searchRadioTypeallRadios=true&searchApType=homePage&severity=3" />
</list>
```

I would like to convert this **XML to Json** . Since this XML is not well formatted and the element contains '&' and '?' Org.json is not converting this . Any help would be really appreciated . I really stuck here .I tried

```
org.json.JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);
                 String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
                System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
```

But no luck. Thanks again

Comment: Which xml? A bit more information would really be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried to use Xstream? I think you could read xml as object and then use json writer: http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html. Sample xml would be helpful for sure.

Comment: @Thomas I have added xml now .@Petro , if you don't mind can you please add the code . I tried Xstream as well but I was not able to .Btw the name of the xml tag will change Dynamically . Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace occurrences of `'&'` by an `&amp;` entity, otherwise it's not valid XML.